# India Canada travel ban?

Tags: canada, india, covid-19, canadian-permanent-residents

I am a Canadian permanent resident
Came to India in March and was flying back on 4th May 2021. Due to the covid 19 strain threat, Canada put a ban on all flights from India to Canada which they have now extended until June 21st 2021. I have already had three flights cancelled because of the ban. They though specify ban is only on a direct flight. So if I travel via Dubai can I get an RT PCR done at Dubai airport and then take a flight to Toronto?

Comment: Are you a citizen of Canada?

Comment: Permanent resident of canada

Answer (score 3):

[This Canadian government page](https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/flying-canada-checklist) addresses pre-arrival testing.

The page says one must take and pass a pre-entry Covid-19 test conducted no more than 72 hours before the scheduled departure time of your flight (or last departure time if you have a transit or layover on the way) to Canada. An RT PCR is an acceptable type of test. According to [this Canada Public Health Agency press release](https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/news/2021/05/government-of-canada-extends-quarantine-measures-and-travel-restrictions.html), the test may not be taken in India or Pakistan. (Thanks to mlc for the pointer)

The test certificate must set forth the following information:

- Traveler name and date of birth
- Name and civic address of the laboratory/clinic/facility that administered the test
- The date on which the test was conducted
- The type of test conducted
- The test results

And I'll add two notes:

1. Getting a Covid-19 test is not the only task you must accomplish to enter Canada. [Further down the same Canadian Government Page](https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/flying-canada-checklist#before) is a list of the requirements. In addition to the Covid-19 test before flying, the list also includes creating a quarantine plan, reserving and paying for a 3-night hotel stay on arrival in a government-approved hotel, registering in advance for a Covid-19 test on arrival (and as an international traveler you must arrive in Canada through an international airport only in Calgary, Montréal, Toronto, or Vancouver), and using ArriveCAN to submit your plans and documents.
2. This answer does not address the related (but unasked) question "Can I fly from India to Dubai?"

Comment: Does Canada have a list of countries to which you should not have travelled in last X days (Like Australia or UK do)?

Comment: @RedBaron I have not seen such a list...which doesn't mean it doesn't exist. But there's no mention of the "where you've been" issue on the pages I've seen, other than the "no current flights" between from India or Pakistan to Canada.

Comment: The "flying to Canada" requirements page indeed makes no mention of where the pre-travel PCR test must or must not be given. However, the [news release on restrictions on flights from India and Pakistan](https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/news/2021/05/government-of-canada-extends-quarantine-measures-and-travel-restrictions.html) says that such passengers are required "to obtain a COVID-19 pre-departure test from a third country before continuing their journey to Canada," which seems to say that a test taken in India would not be accepted. I find all of this very hard to parse.

Comment: @mlc Good find. I'll amend the answer.